# How to use Cordova events in Worklight

Tags: events, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to use some of the Cordova events in WL App. I tried adding below method inside initOptions.js file but it doesn't get called.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

added in the following **inside** initOption.js:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() { WL.Client.init( wlInitOptions ); } , false  );
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload',  function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); });
}

function onDeviceReady() { }
```

Is this the right place to add such type of Cordova events?

Thanks

Comment: Refer to this link 
http://wpcertification.blogspot.in/2012/06/events-in-phonegapcordova-using.html

Comment: @Tirath, I would write that as an Answer rather than a Comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use "deviceready" event of Cordova, it's better directly add your code in wlCommonInit() method than listen on "deviceready" event.

Comment: i changed my adapter approach and now it is working in the initOption.js. thanks